# Whats does the .r stand for?

Tags: tcl, vmd

I'm doing [this tutorial](http://www.ks.uiuc.edu/Training/Tutorials/vmd/tutorial-html/node7.html#SECTION00073000000000000000) which is about scripting in VMD using TCL. At the 7th dot in step 5, what does '*.r*' in `simdata($i.r)` mean?

Answer (score 2):

It has no special meaning in Tcl. It's just that the string formed by concatenating the value in `i` and the string ".r" is the name of one of the members in the array.